# Django timezone isn't working as expected

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views, timezone

I am trying to create an entry app. One of the pages takes entry from the user, the current date and time of my timezone(I have set TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata') and saves it in the database. View function of this page:

```
def new_entry(request):
    date = timezone.now()
    date = date.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    just_date = date.strftime('%d %B %Y')
    just_time = date.strftime('%H:%M')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        ent = Entry(user=request.user, date=date, content=content)
        ent.save()
        return redirect('user')
    return render(request, 'mainapp/new_entry.html', {'date':just_date,'time':just_time})
```

Then in another page I fetch and display all these dates from the database..The view function of that page:

```
def user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    user_entries = Entry.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'mainapp/user.html', {'user_entries':user_entries})
```

In the template of this page I access the date attribute. The problem is when I view the date in the template of the first page it is displayed in UTC and the date on this second page is displayed in the way I want(i.e. Asia/Kolkata timezone). Why is this difference of timezone occuring even though I have clearly set the timezone?

Answer (score 0):

After you set the timezone, you also need to set

```
USE_TZ = True
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes sir i did set  USE_TZ = True in and used timezone.now() as given in the documentation

Comment: @Pranil: the linked page (linking django doc). It has extensive documentation on how to get correct time. Your question doesn't tell us about much of your configuration, templates, etc. But the django docs covers nearly all cases. Take times, and so you will become a timezone expert in Django. It is a very small investment, but you will get other timezone troubles, so such investment is quickly paid off.